# How do I update mysql replicant users new password into slave master. info file

Tags: mysql, passwords, replication

need a quick help. We have a user called replicant which we use as replication user. Due to security, I had to change replicant user's password.

I changed password on master mysql server and slave status shows fine. I know we replicate mysql database itself.

Now, on slave master.info still showing old password, I know it keeps binlog position and I shouldn't be editing it. Now what to do? How to update since slave starts using this file.  help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, don't edit the master.info file directly. The best way to update it is to use the [CHANGE MASTER statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/change-master-to.html).

You can use the MySQL client and run these statements on the replica instance:

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_PASSWORD='...';
START SLAVE;
```

That CHANGE MASTER statement also allows you to change several other options. You can change a subset of them, or even just one, e.g. the password.

On MySQL 8.0.23 and later, use `STOP REPLICA` and `START REPLICA` and `CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO ...` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. Hate to touch production sql servers.  Great help. Thanks, the change master query updated perfectly.